# Can I deny travis-ci access to an organization?

Tags: github, travis-ci

I have a github account which currently has access to my open source projects, as well as some private organizations.

Is there a way to give travis-ci access to only my open source projects and not the organizations, or am I better off creating a separate account for both the open source and the organizations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's possible by way of GitHub's organization-approved application feature: https://github.com/blog/1941-organization-approved-applications

Comment: Do you know if it's possible, as a non-organization administrator, to simply say that I, personally, don't want to give Travis access (regardless of the organization's policies); I only want to use it for personal stuff.

Comment: Does this answer the question? This solution requires you to modify your org as an administrator. Wouldnt it be better for github to only make the request with preferences for the repo in question? That way the whole org is not affected.

Comment: It technically did answer my question -- at least in a way that I could solve my problem. But yes, I did have to involve my organization. I was hoping for a way to do it on my end, but this was good enough.